# Regex Substring Negation

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have the following Regex which I am trying to use to get all Image URLs out of a wget log that point to images other then 150x150 pixels.

```
preg_match_all('/http:\/\/'.$url.'\/wp-content\/uploads\/\S+(?:150x150)\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif)/', $wgetlog, $image_urls);
```

This Regex works. It gives me all URLs that INCLUDE the 150x150 string. If I negate it like so: `(?!150x150)` resulting in:

```
preg_match_all('/http:\/\/'.$url.'\/wp-content\/uploads\/\S+(?!150x150)\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif)/', $wgetlog, $image_urls);
```

It outputs an empty array. (And yes, there are matching URLs in the file)

Thanks for any hints!

Example URL structures would be `http://url.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/name-of-the-file-150x150.png` and `http://url.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/name-of-the-file-1324x130.png`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(?!foo)` is a negative *look ahead*. You're looking for `(?<!foo)` which is a negative *look behind*.

```
/http:\/\/url.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/\S+(?<!150x150)\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif)/
                                            ^^^
```

[**Regex 101 Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/xU1hG9).